# How to mock a gRPC call in C#

Tags: c#, testing, mocking, grpc, grpc-c#

I am trying to set up some testing infrastructure for a c# gRPC service. I am using Grpc.Core version 2.30.0.

My current approach to testing is to start the service on localhost, and then in my test connect to it via a channel on the client.

This works well enough for simple cases, but I'm worried about test reliability and performance. Since an actual (local) network call is occurring, I am worried my unit test will be slower and unreliable. Additionally, since the service is bound to a specific port on localhost, the tests cannot run parallelly since they would conflict when trying to bind to the port.

**I am wondering if there is an idiomatic way to use `CallInvoker` or gRPC interceptors to redirect calls from the client to a given instance of the server in memory, without actually starting the server and using a real connection.**

My thinking is that there would be some way to extend the `CallInvoker` class to resolve methods on a given instance of the server, and then pass that to my client, but so far I haven't found a way.

Thanks!

Comment: a few thoughts: 1. running a test that uses the local network should be reliable enough for most users. 2. you can deal with the problem of port conflicts in your test servers by letting the server bind to autoselect a port (by putting port "0" and then reading which port was selected). see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/90b0ea387e988b8615882e152a5152ed0801ec06/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Tests/MockServiceHelper.cs#L130-L135 as an example.

Comment: Also, you can take a look at the utility package Grpc.Core.Testing - it provides some test doubles that could be useful in your tests. Also see https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.Testing.TestCalls.html